# Sequelize datatypes/column mismatch

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a migration that changes a pkey `id` from an integer to a bigint:

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN id TYPE bigint;
```

On the model definition, `id` is defined as:

```
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER, <--- will change to DataTypes.BIGINT
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
```

But I'm not able to deploy the update to the model definition just yet. I'm only able to run the migration. Will this cause any errors in sequelize to have the model definition mismatch the the column type?